# ABAP in Eclipse issue?

Tags: eclipse, abap

I am trying to open any t-code in Eclipse but unable to do so - It is giving an error "Failed to create the part's controls".

The connection is successful with the backend system and I can browse ABAP objects as well in eclipse.
[image]
Any idea?

Comment: The message says it can't find a file. Is it actually there? Should it be?

Comment: What are the exact steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Solved it. SAP GUI was not installed properly so some file was missing. I re-installed again.

Comment: So add an answer to your question so that others can benefit from it.